# How to perform LIKE in SolrQuery on a single string

Tags: solr

We have a field "url" with a link in it.

For example:

```
https://www.domain.de/g/t/h-zu-b
```

I need to find all documents with a specific domain.

For example:

```
https://www.foo.bar ...
```

So in my database mind I would perform a LIKE-Query to achieve that. but in the context of Solr I'm pretty lost and would be very interested in how that would work?

Comment: Does [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#TheStandardQueryParser-WildcardSearches) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to emulate the LIKE query via a regular expression, for example:

```
url:/http\:\/\/www\.foo\.bar.*/
```

A couple of caveats:

- Make sure you encode the special characters(: . /)
- RegEx searchers are slow
- Make sure your `url` field is indexed

Comment: thanks for your input, the wildcard method with url:https\:\/\/www\.domain\.ru* also worked for that case just so you know, please add it to your answer